# Graph API not returning the correct number of "likes" and no comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments, xfbml

I have been looking for an answer to this problem for some time now and could not find any answer or hint. I guess my problem must be a basic one, and hope someone can show me the right way.

I have a page using the XFBML like and comment plugins:
www.junodownload.com/products/if-this-is-house-i-want-my-money-back-zwei/1802350-02/

Looking directly on the page, I can see 10 "likes" and 1 comment made.

But when using the graph API in debug mode:
graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.junodownload.com%2Fproducts%2Fif-this-is-house-i-want-my-money-back-zwei%2F1802350-02%2F
I see no comments and only 1 Like.

When using the graph API to retreive the comments (the xid is url-encoded):
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.junodownload.com%2Fproducts%2Fif-this-is-house-i-want-my-money-back-zwei%2F1802350-02%2F
I see no data at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see three potential causes:

1. The count that is displayed next to the like button is **not** the number of likes. It consists of likes, shares, comments, and even messages that contain the link of the page to be liked.
2. You are still using on old version of the comment box. You may want to try using href instead of xid or adding migrated=1 to the fb:comment tag. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/.
3. The fb:admins tag of your Open Graph tags is wrong. Run the debugger at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer. We have migrated the comment box, keeping xid as instructed by the doc and will check in a week or so... Concerning 3, this is the only value that worked when adding the social plugins.. the corresponding user userid, or application id would prevent those plugins from appearing, as any other value will do....